# A-frame multiple animations

Tags: html, aframe

I was wondering how it would be possible to create multiple animations on a single object in A-frame. I would like to have a gltf model move 5 spaces back, and then five to the left after the first animation is complete. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

from [Animation - A-Frame](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/animation.html#multiple-animations)

```
<a-entity animation="property: rotation"
          animation__2="property: position"
          animation__color="property: material.color"></a-entity>
```

You can use events to call animations or use **delay** and **duration** attributes